# Dynamic views with two attributes in same table yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2

I have an `APPLICATION` table like this:

```
ID | APP_NAME | PARAM_VIEWS |
1   INDRA       _indra
2   ACIM        _acim
```

In my case, I need to create view action with two attributes `ID` and `PARAM_VIEWS`. If `APP_NAME` is `INDRA`, a view is `_indra`, etc.

My basic controller is

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

How to create an action for my case? I'm still beginner in php and yii 2 framework. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your finding one record using id and you can call $model->PARAM_VIEWS in the render.

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    return $this->render($model->PARAM_VIEWS, [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```